# Is there a way of using Rest API from WooCommerce to retrieve, set up, store, and display cart information in React?

Tags: rest, woocommerce, cart, display

I have read that there is no current way to do this as of 2021, and couldn't find any solutions online so far. So I am hoping someone can help me figure this out, if it is at all possible.

I have tried several different endpoints but they all return 404 and adding to cart does not seem to work, since there is no cart storing the information.

Comment: Cart is stored in session since you can have guests and users. They are stored in db so you can access them this way.